# SectionIndexer for category in android listview

Tags: android

I want to display listview with category e.g Fruits, Vegetable, Others etc.

Fruits

-- Apple

-- Mango

-- Grapes

Vegetable

-- Onion

-- Tomato

Others

-- Belt

---

Data coming in cursor using CursorLoader like,

1  Apple  Fruit

2  Mango  Fruit

3  Grapes Fruit

4  Onion  Vegetable

5  Tomato Vegetable

6  Other  Belt

---

I couldn't find any solution except AlphabetIndexer but it doesn't fill my requirement.
Anyone have idea how to do it??
[Note: I don't have a seperate column like isHeader]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SectionIndexer does not organize your loaded data. Ideally you would have that done before hand with your query or whatever collection is backing it. SectionIndexer merely, allows the adapterView a way to query the list of sections supported, and where they start, end and given a position what section it is in. So it makes the assumption that your data is already sorted.

You can make a SectionIndexer with the following impl

```
@Override
public Object[] getSections() {
    return new CharSequence[] {"Fruit", "Vegetable", "Other"};
}

@Override
public int getSectionForPosition(int position) {
   String text = getItem(position);
   if (text.contains("Fruit") {
      return 0;
   } else if (text.contains("Vegetable") {
      return 1;
   } else {
      return 2;
   }
}

@Override
public int getPositionForSection(int section) {
   String sectionName = (String) getSections()[section];
   for (int i=0,length=getCount(); i < length; i++) {
     if (((String)getItem(i)).contains(sectionName)) {
          return i;
     }
   }
   return getCount();
}
```

FYI this will be super slow, so I would recommend you create an indexed structure whenever you  load more data that caches and prefetches much of the information requested by these methods.

Comment: thanks for reply. I have a question.In getSectionForPosition you are getting String text = getItem(position); so Fruit text will apper for 3 items Apple, Mango, Grapes. But i want to put header just before first item(Apple). How can I achieve this?

Comment: You can do it a couple ways. One would be to create a new ViewType in your adapter that is used when you getView() at the start of a section. It basically returns a view with the secion above it. This has some tradeoffs, especially if you have the onItemClick listener attached.    The other way would be to create a separate entry in your adapter for each section header. so if you had a header at index 0, getView(0, null, list) would return a section view, int getItemViewType(0) would return a value referencing the section type. You have to set them up yourself, the sdk doesn't do this for you